# Looking for any example at all of a Typescript / Visual Studio 2017 / tsconfig.json with outDir and rootDir specified

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am having problems which I will document soon so please bear with me before downvoting.  What I am trying to do is to use a tsconfi.json in a Visual Studio 2017.  The problems I have are:

a) It does not seem to send my json files to anywhere
b) It does not seem to automatically run tsc when a file is saved.

I migrated from VS2015 and ever since then it's been a mess with the Typescript not compiling and possibly the wrong outDir and rootDir specified.  I will soon document my directory structure and tsconfig. Would appreciate any advice / examples anyone can point me to.

Comment: I am having similar issues. I do have VS2015 project that uses Gulp to compile and then push to wwwroot and they're working fine after converting to VS2017. However, new projects without my custom gulpfile is just plain confusing especially (e.g. trying to get intellisense from jquery). I've tried all sorts of things. e.g. install type definition with nu-get (seemingly out of favor), set auto typedefinition in tsconfig, installing type definitions from npm... so far nothing worked and can't find any guidance. Wishing for help. Thanks!